# How to save single value from a select field?

Tags: forms, webforms

I have webform module with multiselect field (Checkbox) User can select all the three.

> PR|Print Required
>   DP|Digital Print Required
>   TP|Print has been taken

**If user selects the last option then, only that option must be saved after submitting even if the other options are selected**. If other two options are selected then as usual those options should be saved.

*In General,
If the user selects the first two options, it should accept the first two options. If user selects third option, then it should save the third option not other two options(If user selects). Example: If user selects all three options, then it should save only the last option.If user selects the last option i.e., Print has been taken, then it should save that irrespective of other selections.*

Comment: Quick thought: why don't you just use JS to limit selection to only one item? Why are you using the multiselect field in the first place?

Comment: No, I don't want to limit it to one item. As you can see I have three options, If the user selects the first two options, it should accept the first two options. If user selects third option, then it should save the third option not other two options(If user selects). Example: If user selects all three options, then it should save only the last option.If user selects the last option i.e., Print has been taken, then it should save that irrespective of other selections.

Comment: Got it now; I suggest updating the question so it's more clear.

Comment: I updated my question. @Topsitemakers Do you have an answer?

Comment: I'm bad with time to write you an example, but check what BenMcCloskey did as that is an easier option. Alternative is to use `hook_form_alter()`, reorder the default callbacks, put yours first and then alter the submitted values. However, I think the JS solution is more user-friendly as the users will then know what's happening. Otherwise, they will select 2-3 options and only 1 will be saved, which is confusing. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use jQuery to deactivate and uncheck the other two checkboxes when the third has been checked. If they uncheck the third, they will all become active.

Your Drupal form will look something like this:

```
<div class="form-checkboxes" id="edit-field-terms-und">
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-terms-und-pr">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="pr" name="field_terms[und][pr]" id="edit-field-terms-und-pr">  <label for="edit-field-terms-und-pr" class="option">Print Required</label>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-terms-und-dp">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="dp" name="field_terms[und][dp]" id="edit-field-terms-und-dp">  <label for="edit-field-terms-und-dp" class="option">Digital Print Required</label>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-terms-und-tp">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="tp" name="field_terms[und][tp]" id="edit-field-terms-und-tp">  <label for="edit-field-terms-und-tp" class="option">Print has been taken</label>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery code would be something like this:

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $("#edit-field-terms-und-tp").click(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
            $('#edit-field-terms-und-pr, #edit-field-terms-und-dp').attr('disabled', true).prop('checked', false );
        } else {
            $('#edit-field-terms-und-pr, #edit-field-terms-und-dp').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });

});
})(jQuery);
```

Haven't tested it, but it should work.